# Rails how do I search in the first and second part of a string in the database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

For my application I want to build a search form that gives back the name of the streets. But when I use `where('street like ?', 'wall')` it only returns: 'Wallstreet' and not for example: 'Second Wallstreet, The Wallstreet'

I want to return also the 'Second Wallstreet, The Wallstreet' but not the a street name with 'Notwallstreet', where 'Wall' is somewhere in the middle.

I have used the 'gem ransack' but there I only found the option contains. And that wil also return 'Notwallstreet'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `%` on both sides of your word to search for a prefix/infix/postfix

```
where('street like ?', '%wall%')
```

PS:

As far as you don't need infix:

```
where('street like ? or ?', '%wall', 'wall%')
```

And here is the thing you should be careful. If you have got an index on the `street` field postfix match won't use it (and prefix will)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer.

Comment: @BartHoekstra oh, I see you don't need infix match. I've edited an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're using postgres you can use SIMILAR TO as described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html).

```
where('street similar to ?', '[[:<:]]Wall')
```